# Why use ASP WebControls over HTMLGenericControls in ASP.NET?

Tags: webforms

I am coming from developing websites by coding HTML/CSS/JavaScript and are currently trying to learn ASP.NET WebForms because SharePoint is built on it.

So far I think pretty much all these Controls make developing harder, rather then easier which they are intended to be. They names and properties are often renamed from their corresponding html-output and unintuitive. And if not only strange names and outputs, then totally unneeded. For example, why use the panel Controller when it justs outputs an simple div? The hide/show logic you can code either server side or client side. And instead of the PanelGroupingText attribute you can code a feildset manually in html. The MultiView controller also seems easier to do with normal html and javascript.

Is their something I have been missing with WebControls or is it needless knowledge and better to use HTMLGenericControls ?

Comment: Try using some of the more complex controls (datagrid) and have a think about what benefits this would give compared to attempting to code it with HTML/CSS/JS

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 
I'm on my way learning GridView and ListView controls and think that they might be good once you know them.